# Проблема с подключением по SSH. Mikrotik

Tags: ssh, mikrotik, l2tp, ipsec

настроил lt2p/ipsec на Mikrotik,все сервера из двух сетей пингуются, но столкнулся с проблемой, с одной сети за первым Микротиком не удается подключится по SSH в другую сеть, в обратную сторону все в порядке, подскажите пожалуйста где искать причину!

**1й микротик** сеть 192.168.20.0/24 l2tp/ipsec ип интерфейса 10.10.5.1
**2й (клиентский)микротик** сеть 192.168.21.0/24 l2tp/ipsec ип интерфейса 10.10.5.99

в обе стороны пингуються, из 21й сети к серверам в 20ю подключение по SSH-есть, из 20й нет

вот что пишет в логах сервера куда я пытаюсь подключиться

```
error: kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Jan 10 17:54:13 client sshd[3223]: Connection reset by 192.168.20.191 port 63381
```